# does JWT replaces Laravel native authentication? should I remove it?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I've just installed JWT in my Laravel application and its working fine (register, login, etc)...

Question: should I remove the native controllers and codes of Laravel authentication?

```
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php
```

Also, JWT is working for my mobile app, however I have a browser-based dashboard in the same application. Should I use JWT in browser too? Or its better to auth with sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT is a good approach I would say as it will make your life easy should in terms of security should you have to build other apis. The jwt approach allows you to secure your applications even if they run on different devices. There are also libraries that helps you integrate a token authentication to your app like IdentityServer of Openiddict (not entirely sure they are available in php to be honest but you should probably find the answer to that quickly)